# How do i redefine myObject's main function, e. g. what myObject() does, without damaging myObject's properties, e. g. myObject.foo?

Tags: javascript

I've got a legit JS question which is kinda hard to explain. Please forgive my unintelligible manner of speaking and try to grasp the idea. :P

In JS objects can have properties. You can assign functions to properties. You can redefine properties of an object without altering its other properties.

```js
var myObject = {};
myObject.myFunction = function() { return 1; };
myObject.bar = "Bar";
myObject.myFunction = function() { return "Another function here"; }
console.log( myObject.bar ); // This is still "bar"
```

But objects can themselves be functions.

**Question 1**: What is the correct term for the function of such a function-object? I'll call it "function-object's main function" below.

*I understand that in JS all funcitons are function-objects, so it's incorrect to say "function of a function-object". But when an object 'foo' can execute two functions: `foo()` and `foo.bar()`, there should be an unambiguous way to distinguish the two in speech.*

As function-objects are objects, they can have properties.

**Question 2**: How do i redefine the function-object's main function while leaving other function-object's properties intact?

Example of what i want:

```js
myFunctionObject = function () { return 1; }
myFunctionObject.bar = "Bar";

// How do i do this...
myFunctionObject = function () { return "Another function here"; }

// ...so that this still returns "Bar"?
console.log( myFunctionObject.bar );
```

The main function of the function-object should be stored somewhere... Some hidden property maybe, e. g. `myFunctionObject.__function__ = function () { return 1; }`?

PS My goal is to understand JS internals. I don't mean any practical use case for this, other than solving some crazy JS-kungfu exercises on [CodeWars](http://codewars.com .

Comment: `foo` is a function, and `foo.bar` is a function.  All functions are simply invokable objects.  What you're asking for is not possible.

Comment: You couldn't do it the way you want, but you could effectively copy all the defined functions over to the new main function

Comment: You can't override the main definition of an object without overwriting this one. Only way is save a local copy of this object, assign theses properties to `this`. Ugly, but functional.

Comment: I see, thank you. I will accept the first answer that mentions that it's impossible and provides a workaround of defining a new function copying properties from the old function to the new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the correct term for the function of such a function-object? I'll call it "function-object's main function" below.

It's called a "function". The properties of the (function) object that are functions themselves are called "methods". If you're talking about methods on a constructor function, you also call them "static methods" (of the "class").

> How do i redefine the function-object's main function while leaving other function-object's properties intact?

You cannot. The call behaviour of a function is immutable in javascript.

All you can do is create a new function, overwrite the variable in which the old one was stored with it, and copy over all properties.

Comment: I want to distinguish the two meanings of the word "function": 1. an object, instance of Function, that has a procedure immutably associated with it. 2. The procedure associated with an instance of Function. I've never seen anyone use "procedure" in JS land.

Comment: Then use "function object" and "function". Though they are immutably associated with each other, the term "function" often means both. To refer to the procedure as a part of the object, you may use "body" or "(compiled) code".

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1**: Adding user defined properties to functions is not recommended, because you don't control what properties functions have, so you can't know for sure if you are going to shadow another property. Since it is not recommended, I don't think there is a correct term for that. Personally, I would call them functions with user defined properties.

**Question 2**: The code `myFunctionObject = function () { return "Another function here"; }` sets `myFunctionObject` to a different object (`function () { return "Another function here"; }`). So, you need to pass the properties of your old object to the new one. One way of doing that is by using functions that add properties instead of adding properties with assignment.

```
function addBar(o){
    o.bar = "Bar";
    return o;
}

myFunctionObject = addBar(function () { return 1; });
myFunctionObject = addBar(function () { return "Another function here"; });
console.log(myFunctionObject.bar);
```

Comment: I want to distinguish the two meanings of the word "function": 1. an object, instance of Function, that has a procedure immutably associated with it. 2. The procedure associated with an instance of Function. I've never seen anyone use "procedure" in JS land.